# Lights Out Algorithm - FInd the minimum number of switches to turn on all switches

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bit-manipulation

The group of switches is located in a horizontal row. The switch on the far right can be turned on or off at any time. Any other switch can only be toggled if the switch to the right of it is on and all other switches to the right are off. All switches are initially off. Create a function that takes n switches and returns the minimum number of switching needed to turn all switches on. It is necessary to output each step of switching the switches.

```
Example: 
n = 3;
[0; 0; 0] --> [0; 0; 1] --> [0; 1; 1] --> [0; 1; 0] --> [1; 1; 0] --> [1; 1; 1];
count = 5.
```

My idea is to test the next switch we want to enable. Then check each switch to the right of it and check the required state.
What solution can you suggest?

Comment: and what did you do so far? Please provide a sample of your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FInd the minimum number of switches to turn on all bulbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35859542/find-the-minimum-number-of-switches-to-turn-on-all-bulbs)

Comment: ^^ Is related, but the switches are subject to different rules.

Comment: what do you mean by "and all other switches to the right are off". if you have 5 switches [0,0,0,0,0] and you turn on the second one, you could do this only if 4th and 5th are off and 3rd is on?

Comment: @trincot: you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually produces a [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) sequence.

While you could certainly implement this in a quite naive way, we can also use the following observation: when we number the indexes in the array from *right* to left, starting with 0 for the rightmost entry, then the index at which a digit should toggle follows this sequence:

```
0 1 0 2 0 1 0 3 0 1 0 2 0...
```

When we number the outputs from 1 onward, then the above mentioned index corresponds to the index of the rightmost 1-bit in that number. This table should illustrate that point:

| output numbering | in binary | index of rightmost 1 | Gray code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00001 | 0 | 00001 |
| 2 | 00010 | 1 | 00011 |
| 3 | 00011 | 0 | 00010 |
| 4 | 00100 | 2 | 00110 |
| 5 | 00101 | 0 | 00111 |
| 6 | 00110 | 1 | 00101 |
| 7 | 00111 | 0 | 00100 |
| 8 | 01000 | 3 | 01100 |
| 9 | 01001 | 0 | 01101 |
| 10 | 01010 | 1 | 01111 |
| ... |  |  |  |

If the input will not exceed 31 (light bulbs) we can use 32-bit manipulations to derive the index of the rightmost 1-bit. For instance `i & ~(i - 1)` returns the least significant bit of `i` that is set -- as a power of 2. To convert a power of 2 to a bit index we can use the little known [`Math.clz32`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/clz32) function.

We can keep track of how many bulbs are on and stop the loop when all are on (without actually counting bulbs from zero in each iteration):

```js
function steps(bulbCount) {
    let i, onCount;
    const bulbs = Array(bulbCount).fill(0);
    console.log(...bulbs);
    
    for (i = 1, onCount = 0; onCount < bulbCount; i++) {
        let index = bulbCount + Math.clz32(i & ~(i - 1)) - 32;
        bulbs[index] ^= 1; // Toggle
        onCount += bulbs[index] || -1; // Either increment or decrement
        console.log(...bulbs);
    }

    return i - 1; // Number of switch actions
}

console.log("Number of switch operations: ", steps(4));
```

For larger number of light bulbs you would need to replace the bit operators with a more "manual" implementation of the same principle, but there is hardly any practical use when you have to wait for over 2<sup>31</sup> outputs to be generated...

### Alternative

We could also use the following observation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Constructing_an_n-bit_Gray_code):

> the <sup>th</sup> Gray code is obtained by computing  ⊕ ⌊/2⌋

While this calculation is simple with 32-bit operators, one needs to build the array from a number in each iteration:

```js
function steps(bulbCount) {
    let i, onCount,
        bits = 0,
        end = (1 << bulbCount) - 1;
    const bulbs = Array(bulbCount).fill(0);
    console.log(...bulbs);
    for (i = 1; bits < end; i++) {
        bits = i ^ (i >> 1);
        console.log(...Array.from(bits.toString(2).padStart(bulbCount, "0"), Number));
    }

    return i - 1; // Number of switch actions
}

console.log("Number of switch operations: ", steps(4));
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for such a complete answer. Indeed, I didn't even think about the Gray Code.